# orientability of a vector bundle plus trivial bundle

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, differential-topology

I'm trying to understand the following: if a vector bundle $E$ over $X$ is not orientable, then neither is $E \oplus \underline{\mathbb{R}}$, where $\underline{\mathbb{R}} = X \times \mathbb{R}$ is the trivial line bundle.

I have not been able to come up with a sketch for a proof, but to start I have been trying to prove: if $V$ is a vector space of dimension $k$, then there is a canonical isomorphism between $\Lambda^k(V)$ and $\Lambda^{k+1}(V \oplus \mathbb{R})$.

I know that both of them will be 1 dimensional, but I'm not sure how to provide the isomorphism. Also, where to go next in the overall proof.

Comment: Can you describe $\Lambda^k(U\oplus V)$ when $U$ and $V$ are vector spaces in terms of the exterior powers of $U$ and $V$?

Comment: $\Lambda^k(U \oplus V) \cong \bigoplus_{i=0}^k \Lambda^i(U) \otimes \Lambda^{k-i}(V)$ is the relationship, I think.


So then $\Lambda^{k+1}(V \oplus \mathbb{R}) \cong \bigoplus_{i=0}^{k+1} \Lambda^i(V) \otimes \Lambda^{k+1-i}(\mathbb{R})$

But we know $\mathbb{R}$ to be a vector space of dimension 1, so $\Lambda^{k+1-i}(\mathbb{R})$ will be 0 except when i=k, in which case it will be 1.

Comment: So what does that tell you about the top exterior power of $V\oplus\mathbb R$?

Comment: That gives us the result that $\Lambda^{k+1}(V \oplus \mathbb{R}) \cong \Lambda^k(V)$. Right? Thank you. Then can I think of orientability as being preserved by isomorphism of the vector spaces at each point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you observed, there is a natural isomorphism $\Lambda^{1+\dim V}(V\oplus\mathbb R)\cong\Lambda^{\dim V}V$ for every vector space $V$. From this you can get that there is an isomorphism of vector bundles $\Lambda^{1+\dim V}(V\oplus\underline{\mathbb R})\cong\Lambda^{\dim V}V$ for every vector bundle $V$ on any space $X$, with $\underline{\mathbb R}$ denoting the trivial 1-dimensional vector bundle.

What you want about orientability follows from this.

Comment: Thank you very much! I feel like I understand now. I appreciate that you led me to understanding the proof on my own terms!

Answer (score 0):

If $E\oplus \mathbb R$ had an orientation, this orientation would give rise to an orientation of $E$. There are a lot of reasons for this, can you think of one?

Reasons could be: Looking at gluing maps (cocycles) with values in $SO(n+1)$ (take basis corresponding to the splitting); looking at orientation reversing curves; continous explicit choice of basis; first Stiefel Whitney class.